# Unable to run self contained .net core deployment on Windows 2008 Service Pack2

Tags: .net-core, windows-server-2008

Running .net core self contained deployment package on Windows server 2008 Service Pack2(x86) machine, fails with message "**The procedure entry point RaiseFailFastException could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll**"

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Create a .net core 2.0 application on Window 7 (x64) with VS 2017
2. Update csproj propertygroup as below

[image]

3. Create package by "dotnet publish -c release -r win-x86"

Above created self contained package works as expected in Windows 7(x64) but NOT in Windows 2008 Service Pack 2. My questions is, .net core 2.0 self contained app supported in Windows 2008 or NOT? If it is supported, how to located KERNEL32.dll?